# Controlling awk array output

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, awk

I have some log files containing FQDNs that I need to aggregate at the third level (three.two.tld); to do that I split it, reverse print the desired number of levels:

```
awk '{print$2}' consolidated.txt |
awk -F. '{for(i=NF;i>NF-3;i--){printf ".%s",$i};printf "\t%s\n",$0}'
```

Leading "." aside, that does what I need where NF>2, e.g.

```
   .com.microsoft.mp       fee3.delivery.mp.microsoft.com
```

However, microsoft.com becomes:

```
   .com.microsoft.com.microsoft      microsoft.com
```

Try as I might, I cannot get my head around how to handle second-level-only domains (example.com) whilst still aggregating the remainder at three. I've tried adding if statements to the array output, but with no success.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please add example raw input and desired output

Comment: Isn't your bad output `.com.microsoft.microsoft.com` instead of `.com.microsoft.com.microsoft`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to chain `awk` scripts, which can easily be combined

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,a,"."); 
        for(i=0; i<3 && i<n; i++) printf ".%s",a[n-i];
        print "\t" $2}' consolidated.txt

.com.microsoft.mp       fee3.delivery.mp.microsoft.com
.com.microsoft  microsoft.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, nothing prevents `i` from being 0 (when NF is 2) and in awk, `$0` is the whole input line.

Change your `for` loop to:

```
for (i = NF; i > 0 && i > NF - 3; i--)
```

Comment: This does correct my code; however, I'm going to accept karakfa's answer as changing the order things are done makes it easier to read/understand what's going on.